# Eclipse windows will not dock on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm running Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it seems impossible to dock windows in the IDE.

Normally, when you drag a tab to a border of the editor pane, it will dock within the pane. This makes it easy to work on several files at once. But as soon as I start to drag a tab, it creates a detached window.  This window has no menu or toolbar and I can find no way to re-attach it to the main editor.

Can anyone suggest a way to make the Eclipse windows behave normally?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was some kind of transient display problem.  Closing Eclipse and rebooting fixed it.  I guess I should have tried that first :S